# Converting measured pressure data to an audio file

Tags: audio, conversion

I do have differential air pressure data, recorded linearly (in 1/240Pa per step) as signed 16bit integer. Given this is the atmospheric air pressure sampled slightly into audible range (100Hz sample rate), the resulting range is roughly +-32.

How would I convert this into audio data for a .wav file? Would a simple scaling by multiplication be the correct approach, using a multiplier that would normalize the resulting data, or should a different conversion be used?

My goal is to use this .wav for analysis, particularly transform into frequency domain and extraction of loudness of low frequency sounds (a brief analysis show peaks at 8.3, 14, 28 and 42 Hz, which partially lie below the traditional ranges of microphones and/or audio device input filters, hence the unusual setup.)

The question does explicitly leave out the zero drift/offset by design of the sensor. I am using a differential pressure sensor with one side in an airtight box, at unspecified but roughly atmospheric pressure, and the other connected to the outside.

Comment: Hello. One of the most common audio loudness measurement algorithm, https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bs/R-REC-BS.1770-4-201510-I!!PDF-E.pdf includes a high pass filter, so you might have to think of your definition of loudness to measure frequencies below 50 Hz.

Answer (score 1):

Audio can be represented in many forms, including in signed 16-bit integers, so you don't have to do anything, your pressure data is already in signed 16-bit integers.

Many audio editing programs have a feature to import raw sample data in 16-bit signed and in many other formats.

So there is no need to do any conversion.

If you then want to save/export the data as an audio file format such as .wav, many audio editing programs allow that too.

For example this is possible with Audacity, a free open source cross-platform multi-track audio editor.

Comment: I suspect that most audio libraries are unable to import raw audio at a 100 Hz sampling frequency. So @charlie-brown will have to either up-sample the data to a supported sampling frequency , or do the math to take into account the actual sampling frequency when doing frequency analysis.

Comment: Audacity at least has no issues with properly formatted .wav files. I may have to resample to get frequency components for smaller blocks (sub-second) though.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an unwieldy amount of data I would convert it to floating point in actual Pascals and save it as a 32-bit float WAV or FLAC file. This way you don't need to deal with calibration.

You just have to make sure that whatever library you are using to read and write the files support a "native" data mode that reads and writes the data as is without type conversion or normalization.

Do not use "lossy" file formats like MP3, AAC, Vorbis etc. These will modify the data and most likely take most of the low frequencies out.

If for some reason your libraries only support 16-bit fixed point, you can save this directly but you need to manually keep track of the calibration. One way to do this is to put the calibration info in the file name.

Comment: OGG is not a format, it's a container for multimedia. For audio, it may contain lossy Vorbis or Speex encoded audio, or lossless FLAC encoded audio. I guess by saying OGG you meant Vorbis.

Comment: Yep. I meant Vorbis . Sorry